# Retorno aninhado no PHP

Tags: php

```
public function form($request)
{
    $cadastro = $this->cadastrar(['cpf' => $request['cpf'], 'nome' => $request['nome']]);

    if ($cadastro) {

        echo 'CPF cadastrado com sucesso';

    } else {

        echo 'Erro ao cadastrar CPF'    

    }

}

public function cadastrar($dados)
{
    if ($this->validar($dados['cpf']))
        return false;

    // Lógica para cadastro dos dados aqui....

}

public function validar($cpf)
{
    $valido = true;

    // Lógica para validação de CPF aqui....

    return $valido;

}
```

No exemplo acima a função `form()` recebe os dados da requisição e invoca a função `cadastrar()` para realizar o cadastro de um CPF. Na função `cadastrar()` é realizada a validação deste CPF invocando a função `validar`.

Caso o CPF informado seja inválido, um booleano é retornado da função `validar()` para a função `cadastrar()` e depois um booleano e enviado da função `cadastrar()` para a função `form()`.

É possível (em caso do CPF ser inválido) enviarmos o retorno da função `validar()` diretamente para a função `form()`?

Obs.: O exemplo citado acima é apenas uma abstração da ideia. Por isto, validar o CPF diretamente na função `form()` não seria uma alternativa de solução para o problema. A ideia é eliminar o 'retorno aninhado' de respostas entre funções (se possível é claro).

Comment: Apesar do que você diz no fim, faria mais sentido chamar a função de validação a partir da função form. Da maneira como fez, a função de cadastro está com uma responsabilidade a mais.

Comment: @bfavaretto Como eu disse, este exemplo que eu dei é apenas uma abstração. Eu estou com um código um pouco mais complexo em produção, aonde o princípio de responsabilidade se aplica. Para não expor um código muito grande, eu preferi exemplificar desta forma.

Comment: Pessoalmente, eu não me lembro de nenhum recurso especial do PHP que possa realizar este objetivo, mas por via de dúvidas, decidi trazer o tópico para discussão na comunidade Stack Overflow.